# How to create a database relationship between 3 entities (items, their categories and additional fields)?

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii, relationship

I'm trying to create a database (using MySQL) for a simple Yii-based website. It will contain a catalog with goods, which are divided into a few categories. The idea is to have a way to add additional fields, specific for each category, and these fields should be fillable for each good in a category.

For example, if I have a category 'wallpapers', they should have additional fields 'color', 'footage', 'facture' etc. An of course these fields must be filled differently for each wallpaper item.

I created a database with 4 tables for it: *items* (which contains items, obviously), *items_categories* (with categories for therm), *items_fields* (contains additional fields) and *items_fields_values* (a support table for many-to-many relationship which also contains a values of related fields).

[My database schema diagram](http://rghost.net/8K2lt2PCB/image.png) *(you need to have at least 10 reputation to attach images)*.

I'm using Yii Framework, and relationships in models described in a such way:

Item model:

```
return array(
        'category' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ItemCategory', 'category_id'),
        'fields' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'ItemField', 'items_fields_values(item_id, field_id)'),
    );
```

ItemField model:

```
return array(
            'itemCategory' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ItemCategory', 'item_category_id'),
            'items' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Item', 'items_fields_values(field_id, item_id)'),
        );
```

ItemCategory model:

```
return array(
            'items' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Item', 'category_id'),
            'itemsFields' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ItemField', 'item_category_id'),
        );
```

How should I define these relationships to have a way to output, add and edit fields to category and their values to specific items?

Comment: Please load your image into this post. This will ensure the question is self contained, and still be available if the image host server is no longer available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is an EAV data model (entity-attribute-value).

An extension might solve your problem for accessing the data. Take a look at https://github.com/yiiext/eav-behavior